# Haskell Dynamic Programming on a Tree

Tags: beginner, haskell, tree, dynamic-programming

Here is my shot at [Homework 8](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis194/spring13/hw/08-IO.pdf) of [CIS-194](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis194/spring13/hw/08-IO.pdf) (from Spring '13). The problem is about a hierarchy of employees at a company (a tree), each node being of type [`Employee`](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis194/spring13/extras/08-IO/Employee.hs), each described by a label (`empName :: String`) and an integer value (`empFun :: Integer`). We need to choose a subset of employees so that no two chosen employees have a parent-child relationship within the tree and the sum of `empFun`s of the chosen employees is maximised.

Some of the outline and structure of this code is based on what was suggested by the document, but I am curious to know if the rest of it is consistent and idiomatic Haskell. I'm not sure what I'm expecting as feedback, but any is welcome.

```
module Party where
    
import Data.List ( sort )
import Data.Tree ( Tree(Node) )
import Employee ( Employee(empFun, empName), Fun, GuestList(..) )

instance Semigroup GuestList where 
    (GL a b) <> (GL c d) = GL (a ++ c) (b + d)

instance Monoid GuestList where
    mempty = GL [] 0

glCons :: Employee -> GuestList -> GuestList
glCons emp (GL a b) = GL (a ++ [emp]) (empFun emp)

moreFun :: GuestList -> GuestList -> GuestList 
moreFun = max

treeFold :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
treeFold f (Node label subtree) = f label (map (treeFold f) subtree) 

nextLevel :: Employee -> [(GuestList, GuestList)] -> (GuestList, GuestList)
nextLevel emp subList = (glCons emp (foldMap snd subList), foldMap (uncurry max) subList)

maxFun :: Tree Employee -> GuestList 
maxFun tree = uncurry moreFun $ treeFold nextLevel tree

getFormattedGL :: GuestList -> String 
getFormattedGL gl = unlines (("Total fun " ++ show (fun gl)) : sort (map empName (emps gl)))
    where fun (GL _ fun) = fun
          emps (GL emps _) = emps

work :: [Char] -> String
work = getFormattedGL . maxFun . read

main :: IO ()
main = readFile "company.txt" >>= putStrLn . work
```

Comment: @bisserlis "Employee" in my post is a URL that leads to the file https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/extras/08-IO/Employee.hs

Comment: Oops! Somehow I glossed right over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is a bug in `glCons`. The employee's fun should get added, not replace the current fun level:

```
glCons :: Employee -> GuestList -> GuestList
glCons emp (GL a b) = GL (a ++ [emp]) (empFun emp)
          --     ^
```

But let's stay on `glCons`. We can expect `glCons` to be used via `foldr`. However, the [`++` operator leads to quadratic behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296694/the-performance-of-with-lazy-evaluation). When we add a single element, we should therefore use `(:)` (and `reverse`, if the order matters):

```
glCons :: Employee -> GuestList -> GuestList
glCons emp (GL a b) = GL (emp : a) (empFun emp + b)
```

Other than that the code seems fine.